# Largest Degree of the fully factored form of $x^n - 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Here by fully factored I mean the expression $x^n - 1$ is fully factored with only integer coefficients.

Ex. $x^6 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)$. In this case the largest degree of the factors is 2.

Similarly $x^{10} - 1 = (x - 1) (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) (x + 1) (x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1)$, which has 4 as the largest degree of its factors.

A quick observation would show that for $n=p$ where p is an odd prime, the largest degree would be $p-1$ and for $n = 2p$ where p is an odd prime, the largest factor would be $p-1$

Is there a general formula to find the largest degree?

Comment: Why do you think that for $n$ odd the largest degree is $n-1$? e.g. $x^9 - 1 = (x^6 + x^3 + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)(x - 1)$. as for a general formula, you may want to read about [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)

Comment: Well if I remember correctly, in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ every polynomial is factorable except linear ones and quadratics with negative discriminant, so we know it is always going to be at most $2$.

Comment: Cyclotomic polynomials are the right resource if we cared about factorizations with integer coefficients. But for factorizations with real coefficients, the largest degree will be either 1 (if all its roots are real) or 2 (if some roots are complex). Can you determine which is the case for general $n$?

Comment: Hint for the case that the factorization over $\mathbb R[X]$ is meant : The only possible real roots are $-1$ and $1$ and $x^n-1$ is squarefree. If the factorization over $\mathbb Q[X]$ is meant, the answe is $\varphi(n)$

Comment: Just to demonstrate that your factorization is not minimal for $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ over $\mathbb{R}$, notice that since it's equal to $\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$ its roots satisfy $x^5=1$. So we can take just the two roots $\zeta=e^{i \frac{2\pi}{5}}$ and its conjugate and get $(x-\zeta)(x-\bar \zeta) = x^2-2\Re(\zeta)x+|\zeta|^2=x^2+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}x+1$, using the fact that the real part of $\zeta$ is $\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}$. You can then work out the other factor similarly or by polynomial long division.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant integer coefficients, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it, As jacob mentioned Cyclotomic polynomials was indeed the way to go.

If f(n) is the greatest power of the factors then a generalized formula would be
$$f(n) = n - \sum_{d|n}f(d)$$

For example f(20) = 20 - f(10)-f(5)-f(4)-f(2)-f(1) = 20 - 4 - 4 - 2 - 1 - 1 = 8
which is indeed the case (I got the values from the wiki page of cyclotomic polynomials).

The page also had this:
$\Phi _{n}(x)={\frac {x^{n}-1}{\prod _{\stackrel {d|n}{{}_{d<n}}}\Phi _{d}(x)}}$ If you consider just the largest exponent of each cyclotomic polynomial we can reach the same formula for f(n)